# read-only numpy array in threading python

Tags: multithreading, numpy, python-multithreading

I have multiple threads that uses numpy array.

```
import threading
import numpy as np
import time


shared_array = np.ones((5, 5))

def run(shared_array, nb_iters):
   k = shared_array**2
   for i in range(nb_iters):
      k+=2

def multi_thread(): 
    jobs = []
    for _ in range(5):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=run, args=(shared_array, 1000000))
        jobs.append(thread)

    for j in jobs:
        j.start()
    for j in jobs:
        j.join()

t0 = time.time()
multi_thread()
print(time.time() - t0)
#result: 6.502177000045776

t0 = time.time()
# we used 1000000 iterations for each thread => total nb of iterations = 5 * 1000000
run(shared_array, 1000000 * 5) 
print(time.time() - t0)
#result: 6.6372435092926025
```

the problem is after adding the numpy array as an argument, the execution time of 5 parallel threads is equal to a sequential execution!

so I want to know how to make a program (similar to this one) parallel,

Comment: Python threads do not run in parallel, only one thread will ever run at a time due to the global interpreter lock

Comment: So what is threading module used for since the threads can not execute the same function? and how can I solve this problem using multithreading
And since only one thread is executing, why there is Barrier and Lock classes in threading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a poor example.  Python has an internal lock (the global interpreter lock, GIL) that means only one thread at a time can be executing Python code.  When you go into numpy, that can run in parallel, but because your array is so small, you are spending almost no time in numpy, so you aren't getting any parallelism to speak of.

Comment: So what is threading module used for since the threads can not execute the same function? and how can I solve this problem using multithreading
And since only one thread is executing, why there is Barrier and Lock classes in threading?

Comment: Python threading is great for I/O bound workloads, and workloads that spend a lot of time in C modules like numpy, pandas, and TensorFlow, which release the lock for you.  Threading is useless for CPU-bound pure-Python workloads.